# How to register telerick controls in SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am using Sharepoint 2010. I want to know how to use telerick controls in SharePoint designer 2010. I want to register telerik control in V4 Masterpage for a team site.

How do I register telerick controls in SharePoint Designer 2010?

Answer (score 0):

The Control would need to be in the GAC or in the Bin fodler of your site, and it would need an entry in the site's web.config as a SafeControl. After that you can use it as you would in a regular ASP.NET site